# Android Service Process Attribute

Tags: android

If I define a service in two APK's, and attempt to start those services on device boot time, and both services have the same process name, will they both start up?  Or is the Android OS smart enough to know that a "process" by the same name is already running?  Or does this just mean that they both share the same VM or OS level process?

APK #1

```
<service android:name=".app.MessengerService" android:process="process_name" />
```

APK #2

```
<service android:name=".app2.MessengerService" android:process="process_name" />
```